# Pre-fill Woocommerce checkout fields with Url variable before session created

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, get, checkout

I have wordpress site running woocommerce with a few products. I want to send my customer a url to their product which includes their name and email so i can pre-fill name and email on woocommerce checkout page. the link will take customer to the product item page, where they can view product details and click "add to cart".

Link example: `http://example.com/product/myitem/tu_em=name@example.com&tu_name=theFirstName`

I tried to use [Pre-fill Woocommerce checkout fields with Url variables saved in session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50356459/pre-fill-woocommerce-checkout-fields-with-url-variables-saved-in-session/50357363#50357363) answer code but you need to already have a woocommerce session created, which doesnt happen until you click "add to cart"

How can i pre-fill my checkout fields page from the url to a product item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Pre-fill Woocommerce checkout fields with Url variables saved in session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50356459/pre-fill-woocommerce-checkout-fields-with-url-variables-saved-in-session/50357363#50357363)
answer code and initialize a session cookie before add to cart action, using the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'initiate_customer_session_cookie' )
function initiate_customer_session_cookie(){
    // Ensure that Woocommerce session cookie is initiated
    if ( isset(WC()->session) && ! WC()->session->has_session() ) 
        WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Hmm its not working, the script isnt creating the session cookie. It's working exactly like the other script was. I dont know if it would make a difference but I purged my breeze cache and disabled caching on the product item page (just in case), but it didnt do anything. Also, removed typo } for line 7

Comment: Thank you for the related thread. I added the function listed to manually create a new session, and it works. So currently i have both yours and @sally_CJ, i dont know why yours wouldnt work by itself, I should probably figure out, but for now it guess its not a huge deal if its creating sessions for every visitor. thank you Loic!! Happy New Year!